# How can i fill and then display this void*** matrix in C?

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, struct, void-pointers

Context: I need to create a board game with a 2D array using void***, in each slot i have to initially put a Struct "Tierra" and then in later turns i can put a Struct "Bomba"

The 2D array is a global variable, and i kinda have something

Here is the struct Tierra:

```c
typedef struct Tierra{
    int vida; // random health (1-3)
    int es_tesoro; // 1 or 0 (5% chance of having a treasure)
} Tierra;
```

Here is the function to create the array, this function can only recieve dimension as a parameter and has to be void():

```c
void*** tablero;
int dimension;
const int chance[5]={1,2,3,4,5};

void IniciarTablero(int n){
    tablero = malloc(n*sizeof(void**));
    if(tablero == NULL){
        printf("%s", "error con la memoria \n");
        exit(1);
    }   
    for( int i=0 ; i<n ; i++){
        tablero[i] = malloc(n*sizeof(void*));
        if (tablero[i] == NULL){
            printf("%s", "error con la memoria \n");
            exit(1);
        }
        for( int j=0 ; j<n ; j++){
            Tierra* tierra;
            tierra->vida = (rand() % 3) + 1;
            int probabilidad = (rand() % 100);
            int contenido = 0;
            for (int c=0 ; c<5 ; c++){
                if(probabilidad==chance[c]){
                    contenido = 1;
                }
            }
            tierra->es_tesoro = contenido;
            tablero[i][j] = tierra;
        }
    }
}
```

and here is my function to display it:

```c
void MostrarTablero(){
    for (int i=0 ; i<dimension ; i++){
        for (int j=0 ; j<dimension ; j++){
            Tierra* imprimir = (Tierra*)tablero[i][j];
            printf("%d | ",imprimir->vida);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return;
}
```

Whenever i try calling IniciarTablero() and then MostrarTablero in main, it gives me Segmentation Fault error, and it doesn't even get in MostrarTablero(). I think the problem might be in how i give a value to tablero[i][j] but i'm new in c and i don't know how to use pointers yet.

Thank you in advance and hope you have a good day/night. <3

Comment: My first thought on seeing this: [The Tree Star Programmer](https://wiki.c2.com/?ThreeStarProgrammer)

Comment: Don't use `void*`. You know exactly which types you want to store there, so you can use a _variant_: basically a struct that contains a union. If your board dimensions are rectangular, avoid allocating every row separately. You can allocate a 1D array and index it as if it's 2D. This is what compilers do with _actual_ 2D arrays.

Comment: "with a 2D array using void***"  This part doesn't make any sense. It rather seems that you would benefit of using a pointer to a 2D array of structs? `void***` is not helpful.

Comment: I don't understand either, but they won't let me change the tablero variable type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented by @paddy, you should not use `void *` as a pointer type
in this case. Besides you are *not* allocating the memory for each
entity of `struct Tierra`.
Would you please try instead:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

typedef struct Tierra {
    int vida; // random health (1-3)
    int es_tesoro; // 1 or 0 (5% chance of having a treasure)
} Tierra;

Tierra ***tablero;
int dimension;
const int chance[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

void IniciarTablero(int n)
{
    tablero = malloc(n * sizeof(Tierra ***));
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        tablero[i] = malloc(n * sizeof(Tierra **));
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            Tierra *tierra = malloc(sizeof(Tierra));    // missing in the original code
            tierra->vida = (rand() % 3) + 1;
            int probabilidad = (rand() % 100);
            int contenido = 0;
            for (int c = 0; c < 5; c++) {
                if (probabilidad == chance[c]) {
                    contenido = 1;
                }
            }
            tierra->es_tesoro = contenido;
            tablero[i][j] = tierra;
        }
    }
}

void MostrarTablero()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < dimension; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < dimension; j++) {
            Tierra *imprimir = tablero[i][j];
            printf("%d | ", imprimir->vida);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main()
{
    dimension = 4;              // just for example
    IniciarTablero(dimension);
    MostrarTablero();

    // don't forget to free() memory after use

    return 0;
}
```

Please note it is omitted to check the return values of `malloc()` just
for simplicity to focus on the essentials.

Btw if the value `dimension` is fixed (not dynamically assigned),
it will be better to use simple 2-D array of `struct Tierra`.

Comment: I undestand your solution, but the problem is that later in the game you have to put Bombs (other struct) in slots of the board, and that struct has other atributes and a different size. Still thank you very much, I didn't know that i had to put a malloc to create Tierra*. take care <3

Comment: It worked, i needed to add that malloc, thank you <3